# Lanzar accion PHP en la misma página

Tags: php, html, pdf

Quiero probar un reporte, en la pagina donde estoy tengo siguiente codigo:

```
<!-- MODULO CABECERA -->
<?php
    include "views/modules/cabecera.php";
 ?>

 <!-- MODULO BOTONERA -->
 <?php
    include "views/modules/botonera.php";
 ?>

<?php

 if(isset($_POST['pdfPrint'])){

    require_once "../lib/tcpdf/tcpdf/tcpdf.php";

    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Miguel Caro');
    $pdf->SetTitle($_POST['reporte_name']);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false); 
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(20, 20, 20, false); 
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 20); 
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
    $pdf->addPage();

    $content = '';

    $content .= '
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

      <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>DNI</th>
            <th>A. PATERNO</th>
            <th>A. MATERNO</th>
            <th>NOMBRES</th>
            <th>AREA</th>
            <th>SUELDO</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    ';

    $content .= '</table>';

    $content .= '
        <div class="row padding">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
                <span>Pdf Creator </span><a href="http://www.redecodifica.com">By Miguel Angel</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    ';

    $pdf->writeHTML($content, true, 0, true, 0);

    $pdf->lastPage();
    $pdf->output('Reporte.pdf', 'I');
}

?>


<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Reportes
        <small>Reporte de Lote y Orden de Trabajo</small>
      </h1>
  </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content container-fluid">
    <br><br><br>

      <div class="reporte">
            <input type="text" id="loteReport" class="text" placeholder="Digite el lote">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="reportBtn">Buscar lote para reporte</button>
      </div>
      <form action="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="pdfPrint">Imprimir</button> 
      </form>
      <br><br>

      </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Cada vez que le doy al boton `imprimir`, me devuelve a la página de inicio de mi proyecto, como puedo hacer para que me abra el "`pdf generado`" o cual es mi error en el codigo?

(Tengo una lista blanca para los enlaces no si se tambien afecte a la hora de enviart el `POST`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu formulario, tienes declarada la `action="POST"`,
cuando eso va en `method`, tu formulario debería quedar de la siguiente manera,

```
<form action="" method="POST">.....
```

Cuando haces la impresión del pdf, agrega un `die();`, tu código continua ejecutando, y agrega las lineas que están en la parte inferior, haciendo que el pdf no se vea.

```
....
$pdf->output('Reporte.pdf', 'I');
die();
```

Comment: Igual sigue, me lanza al inicio

Comment: en alguno de los dos ficheros que incluyes en la parte superior no haces la redirección al inicio?

Comment: esos ficheros solo cargan otros php, como son la botonera y la cabecera, cada vez que toco el boton, me lanza al inicio y la url pasa a esto: `http://localhost:8080/empaque/POST?pdfPrint=` tiene algo que ver que este vacio despues del `=`?

Comment: deja tu form de la siguiente forma `<form action="" method="POST">....`